# How to use javascript variables in shopify's liquid? like vue.js

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

some.liquid

```
<div>this is {{year}}</div>

<script>
var year = ''
if (location.hostname == 'stackoverflow.com') {
  year = 'good'
} else {
  year = 'nood'
}

</script>
```

Obviously, the idea above cannot be implemented, so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it can't work that way is that Shopify doesn't execute JavaScript on their server when parsing liquid file. So you want to manually modify that element using JavaScript

```html
<div id="my-element"></div>

<script>
const myElement = document.getElementById('my-element');

var year = ''
if (location.hostname == 'stackoverflow.com') {
  year = 'good'
} else {
  year = 'nood'
}

myElement.innerText = `This is ${year}`

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been troubled by this problem for a long time